# How to change text "You have no items in your shopping cart." in minicart in magento 2

Tags: magento2, localisation, mini-cart, i18n

How to change the text "You have no items in your shopping cart." in mini cart in Magento 2

[image: art]

Comment: i sure about this text is come from the content.html  file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check with below path.

```
app/design/frontend/Magento/theme-name/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/noItems.phtml
```

Comment: no text not changed

Comment: let me try from my side.

Comment: can you please check your theme module Magento_Checkout - have any content.html file.

Comment: this path - Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/content.html

Comment: i will try it sir

Answer (score 1):

Create `en_US.csv` file in your module `vendor/Module/i18n/en_US.csv`
Add below text in `en_US.csv` file.

> "You have no items in your shopping cart.","Add Your Changed Text Here."

Flush Your Magento cache `php bin/magento c:f`

Comment: text not changed

Comment: please clear your cache properly, it might be some cache issue. or you can redeploy the content also.

Comment: i clear it but it not happen

Comment: This does not work for me either (Other translations do). Tried with/without full stop & quotes.
Even though I see in the DOM it is 'data-bind="i18n: 'You have no items in your shopping cart.'"'. Stupid Magento.

Answer (score 0):

**Copy This File Into Your Theme :-**

```
/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/content.html
```

**See Line no. 78**

```
 translate="'You have no items in your shopping cart.'"
```

You can change according to your requirements at above place.

Remove **var** folder from root and remove **`pub/static/frontend`** folder.

You must have run command **`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`**

Clear your browser cache and check.